# How To display the server data which is in json format in the navigation drawer?

Tags: android, json, navigation-drawer

I want to display the employee name from the server data in the navigation drawer activity

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Check for success tag

    String companyCode = "VO";
    String loginBranch ="VO02";
    String employName ="";

    try {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("companyCode", companyCode));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("employeeCode", employCod));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("empBranch", branchCod));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passWord", password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loginBranch",loginBranch));

        Log.d("request!", "starting");

        // getting product details by making HTTP request
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
```

Comment: How does your json look like?

Comment: {"empName":"JOS BABU                      ","errorMsg":"SUCCESS","errorFlag":"S","empAttendanceFlag":"N","loginBrName":"IT OFFSHORE - BANGALORE"}

Comment: Just do employName = json.getString("empName");

Comment: And i want to display the employee name in the next acivity

Comment: Just pass it in the intent as string and get it in the next activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to display dynamic contents in the navigation view. You can instead use an activity with a listview or recyclerview.

Comment: But i need to display the profile name as just like the navigation drawer in gmail app

Comment: Do you want to display it on a header or as navigationview item

Comment: ya itz in the header.. ! . now i got it..thank uu